# Ansible and Jinja2 variables combination

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a playbook that generates bash script of two Ansible lists.

In Jinja2 template file I am trying to run `for` loop on one Ansible list and then run another `for` loop inside it based on output from first one.

Here is my Ansible `defaults.yml`:

```
##################################
#        FIRST LOOP              #
##################################

prefix_list:
  - prefix1
  - prefix2

##################################
#         SECOND LOOP            #
##################################
prefix1:
  - kola
  - wlcom
  - linkstory



prefix2:
  - kola
```

Jinja2 Template:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +'%Y.%m' -d "month ago")
exdate=$(date +'%Y.%m' -d "{{ exdate }} months ago")
{% for prefix in prefix_list %}
    {% for index in prefix %}
        {{ index }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Result:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +'%Y.%m' -d "month ago")
exdate=$(date +'%Y.%m' -d "12 months ago")
            p
            r
            e
            f
            i
            x
            1
                p
            r
            e
            f
            i
            x
            2
```

Comment: Please, show, how you pass `prefix_list` to Jinja. Looks like it is a list of strings and in second loop you enumerate chars

Comment: I posted both ansible list (top of post) and jinja file (middle of post).
{% for prefix in prefix_list %}
    {% for index in prefix %}
        {{ index }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: From your question it is unclear how do you invoke template compilation and how are variables passed. From result I suppose that there are separate lists of strings - `prefix_list`, `prefix1` etc. So you should somehow transform them before template processing

Comment: I have ansible task that invoke template compilation.

- name: Copy backup script
  template:
     src: autoelkbackup.sh.j2
     dest: "{{ work_dir }}/autoelkbackup.sh"
     mode: 0755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`vars` lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/vars.html) to refer to variables (instead of iterating over the characters in their names, as you do now).

Your internal loop should be:

```
{% for index in lookup('vars', prefix) %}
```

---

<sup>Also check how to [control whitespace in Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#whitespace-control), because the output you'll get with your current code will be strangely indented.</sup>

Comment: Big thanks to you it works, but one little thing .
 You need to have Ansible 2.5 and higher.

Comment: Yes, that's written at the top of the page I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much experienced with Ansible, but I guess you should try to nest your lists in `defaults.yml`

### Case 1 - nested lists

(This is what your template expects)

```
prefix_list:
  -
    - kola
    - wlcom
    - linkstory

  -
    - kola
```

### Case 2 - dictionary

(When you need `prefix1` and `prefix2` in your template

```
prefix_list:
  prefix1:
    - kola
    - wlcom
    - linkstory

  prefix2:
    - kola
```

In this case Jinja loop should be fixed this way

```
{% for prefix in prefix_list %}
    {% for index in prefix_list[prefix] %}
        {{ index }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working .
Here is the result:
`#!/bin/bash`
`date=$(date +'%Y.%m' -d "month ago")`
`exdate=$(date +'%Y.%m' -d "12 months ago")`
         `prefix1`
             `prefix2`